Accounting for recall period in proportion meta-analysis
We are conducting a meta-analysis of "prevalence" of event-type exposures, e.g. "have you been physically assaulted in the past X months". We are trying to adjust for different recall periods.
While these outcomes are usually reported as proportion exposed in a given recall period, I think the underlying process is effectively an event rate. So, I was hoping some kind of event rate model could help incorporate different recall periods? The problem is, we only have population proportions, and the individual-level events are effectively censored at 1 (e.g. "any Y in X months" not "how many Y in X months"). We will not have access to the individual-level data.
Can you suggest any guidance on adjusting for recall period in proportion meta-analysis (besides stratification)? I'm happy to abandon the event-rate idea if there is a better way.
EDIT 1: adding simulated data for testing:
X = data.frame(
  s  = c('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'), # study label
  n  = c( 40, 80, 60,250,150, 30, 15, 80, 50), # study size
  w  = c( 90, 30,360, 15,720, 30, 60,120, 30), # recall periods
  f1 = c(  1,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  0,  1)) # covariate
B.0 = log(.01) # true incidence rate
B.f1 = log(0.5) # f1 halves the rate
for (s in 1:nrow(X)){
  X[s,'r'] = exp(B.0 + B.f1 * X$f1[s]) # true rate for study
  # r = rexp(X$n[s],1/X$r[s])            # random individual rates
  r = X[s,'r']                         # fixed individual rates
  e = rpois(X$n[s], r * X$w[s])        # random individual events
  X[s,'y'] = sum(pmin(e,1))            # number with any event
}

EDIT 2: adding example JAGS model.
model{
  for (s in 1:S){ # studies
    r[s] <- exp(b.0 + b.f1 * f1[s]) # modelled rate
    p[s] <- min(1-1e-6, 1 - exp(- r[s] * w[s])) # poisson P(e > 0)
    y[s]  ~ dbin(p[s], n[s]) # num individuals with P(e > 0)
  }
  # estimands
  b.0  ~ dunif(-10,10) # base rate
  b.f1 ~ dunif(-10,10) # covariate effect
}

this model mostly works, but tends to overestimate B.0. It seems like there might be a consistent bias which could be adjusted away, but I'm stuck how to proceed.

Straight-up maximum likelihood estimation under the model you are assuming gives unbiased estimates for the dataset you provided.
fitfun <- function(b, y, f1, n, w) {
   r <- exp(b[1] + b[2] * f1)
   p <- 1 - exp(- r * w)
   d <- dbinom(y, n, p, log=TRUE)
   -sum(d)
}

out <- replicate(100000, {

   for (s in 1:nrow(X)){
     X[s,'r'] = exp(B.0 + B.f1 * X$f1[s]) # true rate for study
     r = X[s,'r']                         # fixed individual rates
     e = rpois(X$n[s], r * X$w[s])        # random individual events
     X[s,'y'] = sum(pmin(e,1))            # number with any event
   }

   res <- optim(c(-3,0), fitfun, y=X$y, f1=X$f1, n=X$n, w=X$w)
   return(res$par)

})

c(B.0, B.f1)
apply(out, 1, mean)

This yields:
> c(B.0, B.f1)
[1] -4.6051702 -0.6931472
> apply(out, 1, mean)
[1] -4.604044 -0.686925


Thanks. Maybe something is funky with my JAGS. I also get much better estimates of B.0 and B.f1 when using fixed individual rates vs random individual rates, though I think the latter are more plausible in reality.

If the event of interest is having been assaulted at least once over the past X months, then you can just treat this as an incidence rate. This would be the same as fitting a parametric survival regression model with an exponential distribution.
Say, these are the data from one study:
dat <- data.frame(t = rep(6,10),
                  y = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0))

Then a survival regression model with an exponential distribution fitted with:
library(survival)
res <- survreg(Surv(t,y) ~ 1, data=dat, dist="exponential")
summary(res)

yields:
Call:
survreg(formula = Surv(t, y) ~ 1, data = dat, dist = "exponential")
            Value Std. Error    z       p
(Intercept) 3.401      0.707 4.81 1.5e-06

Scale fixed at 1

Exponential distribution
Loglik(model)= -8.8   Loglik(intercept only)= -8.8
Number of Newton-Raphson Iterations: 5
n= 10

where the intercept is minus the log incidence rate. We can double-check this by directly computing the log incidence rate based on the total number of events and total follow-up time, which we could get with:
library(metafor)
dat2 <- escalc(measure="IRLN", xi=sum(dat$y), ti=sum(dat$t))
summary(dat2)

which yields:
       yi     vi    sei      zi   pval   ci.lb   ci.ub 
1 -3.4012 0.5000 0.7071 -4.8100 <.0001 -4.7871 -2.0153 

In fact, this is also identical to fitting a Poisson regression model with log(t) as an offset:
res <- glm(y ~ 1 + offset(log(t)), family=poisson, data=dat)
summary(res)

which yields:
Call:
glm(formula = y ~ 1 + offset(log(t)), family = poisson, data = dat)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -3.4012     0.7071   -4.81 1.51e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 6.4378  on 9  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 6.4378  on 9  degrees of freedom
AIC: 12.438

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6

This assumes a constant hazard rate. But it shows that you can frame this as a standard meta-analysis of log incidence rates (i.e., compute the log incidence rates for all studies and then pool them together using standard meta-analytic methods).

Thanks. This is helpful, but I am more interested in the underlying incidence rate, not incidence proportion, with the same constraint that we only know how many had 1+ events in each study. I have a model in JAGS like: y[s] ~ dbin(p[s], n[s]); p[s] <- 1 - exp(-r[s] * w[s]); r[s] <- exp(b.0), where the definition of p[s] derives from the poisson probability of P(y>0). where b.0 is the true log incidence rate (simulated data), and w is the study recall period. This mostly works, but there is still bias in estimating b.0. I will add toy data to my question.
